# how to make library from c++ class files (.cpp/.h) so that this can be included in other programs as #include <cplong>?

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, libstdc++

for cplong class files are cplong.cpp/cplong.h in [github.com/zava8/plong --- src/](http://github.com/zava8/plong)

i have tested these classes in main.cpp . it is working fine?

now i am trying for including cplong as library in other programs as:
#include

for this i created makefile as :

```
viml@viml ~/maigit/eclp/plong $ cat src/makefile 
NAME=libplong.so
CPPFLAGS=-g -o $(NAME) -fPIC -shared
FILE=cplong.cpp

$(NAME): $(FILE)
    g++ $(FILE) $(CPPFLAGS)
```

and install.sh as :

```
viml@viml ~/maigit/eclp/plong $ cat src/install.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "building and installing cplong library."
make
sudo mv libplong.so /usr/lib/
sudo cp cplong.h /usr/include/
echo "finished installing.  to use library, add '-lplong' as a flag"
```

after that i try to use this in other programs (say uzeplong.cpp) as :

```
// github.com/zava8/plong uze_kesiz/uzeplong.cpp
#include <cplong.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cplong a(0x5C, -1);
cout << "a is: " << a << endl; // out should be 5.C (heks plong)
return 0;
}
```

after this compiling as :

```
g++ -lplong uzeplong.cpp
```

when compiling getting errors as undefined reference .....

so i need help to create and use library from c++ class (*.cpp and *.h)?

cplong.cpp and cplong.h are in [github.com/zava8/plong src/](http://github.com/zava8/plong)

Comment: It should be `g++ uzeplong.cpp -lplong`.

Comment: `sudo mv libplong.so /usr/lib/` Och no, don't stain your system with manual modifications. Manual stuff belongs to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: yes it worked after g++ uzeplong.cpp -lplong

Comment: this issue got resolved after using :  g++ uzeplong.cpp -lplong. instead of /usr/lib /usr/include local path is good.